# Wordpress qTranslate x - How to show just flags

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, qtranslate-x

I'm using the qTranslate x plugin on my website but i just want to show the flags at the menu but it is shows with text like that `English | Flag`

How can i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue, and resolved this putting a `<img>` tag on the label of the menu item.
Like this one:

```
<img src="/[YourWPDirectory]/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate-x/flags/gb.png" alt="English" >
```

The plugin got default flags images that you can use. You can change the "gb.png" to other countries, like "br.png" for Brazil, "fr.png" for France, and so on. I dont know exactly which countries does it have as it is part of the plugin files, but it would also work if you upload your own flag image too and link it the same way.

For more detailed information, i used this website: http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/add-qtranslate-flags-menu-2-quick-easy-ways/